# Receiving returned data from firebase callable functions

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm playing with Callable HTTPS-functions in iOS. I've created and deployed the following function:

```
export const generateLoginToken = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    const uid = data.user_id
    if (!(typeof uid === 'string') || uid.length === 0) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', 'The function must be called with one argument "user_id" ');
    }

    admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid)
    .then((token) => {
        console.log("Did create custom token:", token)
        return { text: "some_data" };
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error creating custom token:", error)
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'createCustomToken(uid) has failed for some reason')
    })
})
```

Then I call the function from my iOS-app like this:

```
let callParameters = ["user_id": userId]
    self?.functions.httpsCallable("generateLoginToken").call(callParameters) { [weak self] (result, error) in
    if let localError = self?.makeCallableFunctionError(error) {
        single(SingleEvent.error(localError))
    } else {
        print("Result", result)
        print("data", result?.data)
        if let text = (result?.data as? [String: Any])?["text"] as? String {
            single(SingleEvent.success(text))
        } else {
            let error = NSError.init(domain: "CallableFunctionError", code: 3, userInfo: ["info": "didn't find custom access token in the returned result"])
            single(SingleEvent.error(error))
        }
    }
}
```

I can see on the logs that the function is invoked on the server with the right parameters, but I can't seem to the get data that is being returned from the function back into the app. It seems that the `result.data` value is `nil`for some reason, even though I `return {text: "some_data"}` from the cloud function. **How come?**

Comment: Can you show the code of your Function?

Comment: Also, what do you get if you call your Function via a browser?

Comment: You could be doing something wrong in your function code.  Without seeing it, there's no way to tell.

Comment: Sorry.. I've added the cloud function :) It's an `onCall` function, I don't know how I would call it via a browser. When I try to paste the URL directly into an browser or do `curl` from the terminal, I get `{"error":{"status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","message":"Bad Request"}}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yikes! The issue was that I forgot to return the actual promise from the cloud function. This function is working:

```
export const generateLoginToken = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    const uid = data.user_id
    if (!(typeof uid === 'string') || uid.length === 0) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', 'The function must be called with one argument "user_id" ');
    }

    return admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid)
    .then((token) => {
        console.log("Did create custom token:", token)
        return { text: "some_data" };
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error creating custom token:", error)
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'createCustomToken(uid) has failed for some reason')
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for making me double check. For future reference: returning inside of a regular callback does NOT work. Must use promises.

Comment: Is there any additional steps other than adding this function to index.js? I copied it then deployed it "firebase deploy" through terminal but I get this error "Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
"

Comment: Hmm.. Yes, there are a few other steps. You need to initialize the admin SDK with your service account key. You should probably find a tutorial for how to make the "createCustomToken" work. Here's how I do: https://justpaste.it/57hqz . And then I deploy with "firebase deploy --only functions". Also follow this link, it's should cover the basics: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started